# why is numba so much faster on this simple summation?

Tags: python, numpy, cython, numba, f2py

I have a public notebook where python, numpy, numba, cython, and fortran are compared on simple summation:

https://gist.github.com/denfromufa/7727874c4fe1e7e174ed953930e93bbc

Why is numba so much faster?

Comment: Because you run the numba one on a single value, and the others on an array.

Comment: `%timeit sumr(int(1e6))` (line 7)

Comment: @DavidW: `sumr` has a loop inside it that uses `range`.

Comment: Yes sorry my mistake!

Comment: It's still not really doing the same thing though - the cython/numpy one are creating an array/range, (and the creation of that is being timed too) and then adding together all the values in that array. The numba doesn't allocate any memory, doesn't do any indexing, (and if it's really clever could be replaced with `n*(n-1)/2`, which would be a clever optimisation but only valid for the numba one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @DavidW, you aren't really doing a comparison of identical algorithms. Below I've written two separate functions for each cython and numba that do the same thing. The first operates on an array, the second is just given an integer:

Cython:

```
cpdef long cy_sum(long[:] A):
    cdef long i, n = A.shape[0], s = 0
    for i in range(n):
        s += A[i]
    return s

cpdef long cy_sum2(long i):
    cdef long s, x
    s = 0
    for x in range(i):
        s += x
    return s
```

Numba:

```
@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def nb_sum(A):
    s=0
    n = A.shape[0]
    for i in range(n):
        s += A[i]
    return s

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def nb_sum2(i):
    s=0
    for x in range(i):
        s+=x
    return s
```

Testing to make sure they give the same results:

```
N = int(1e6)
d = np.arange(N, dtype=np.int64)

print np.allclose(nb_sum(d), cy_sum(d))   # True
print np.allclose(nb_sum2(N), cy_sum2(N))  # True
```

And timings on my hardware:

```
%timeit cy_sum(d)
%timeit nb_sum(d)

1000 loops, best of 3: 416 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 237 µs per loop

%timeit cy_sum2(N)
%timeit nb_sum2(N)

10000000 loops, best of 3: 63.5 ns per loop
10000000 loops, best of 3: 187 ns per loop
```

I wouldn't draw too many conclusions from a micro-benchmark like this, but at least now equivalent implementations are being compared.